# Determining if the mouse is over a specific layout

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to determine if the mouse is over a specific Layout. I would like to know if the mouse is over a specific QVBoxLayout. This QVBoxLayout may contain other widgets. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do directly.

However, it might be possible to fake it. You can put a custom widget inside the layout, use `setMouseTracking(true)` and override the widget's `enterEvent()`. This way you can execute your code when the mouse enters that widget, for example emit a signal, and since the widget will fill the layout, it will be identical to the mouse cursor entering the layout.

The downside is now you have lost the original layout, as it will only contain the "hover listener" widget, but you can put another layout in the listener widget and use that to put in other widgets.